# Spyder is crashing while idling in background

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I can launch Spyder, then do absolutely nothing with it and after a while the window just disappears. I've run it from the command prompt with debug-verbose and get this just before it crashes -

```
2020-11-24 19:03:01,283 [DEBUG] [spyder.plugins.editor.utils.autosave] -> Autosave triggered
2020-11-24 19:04:01,292 [DEBUG] [spyder.plugins.editor.utils.autosave] -> Autosave triggered
2020-11-24 19:05:01,277 [DEBUG] [spyder.plugins.editor.utils.autosave] -> Autosave triggered
2020-11-24 19:06:01,282 [DEBUG] [spyder.plugins.editor.utils.autosave] -> Autosave triggered
Assertion failed: Connection reset by peer [10054] (C:\ci\zeromq_1599741307349\work\src\signaler.cpp:368)
Assertion failed: Connection reset by peer [10054] (C:\ci\zeromq_1599741307349\work\src\signaler.cpp:368)
Assertion failed: Connection reset by peer [10054] (C:\ci\zeromq_1599741307349\work\src\signaler.cpp:368)
Assertion failed: Connection reset by peer [10054] (C:\ci\zeromq_1599741307349\work\src\signaler.cpp:368)
Assertion failed: Connection reset by peer [10054] (C:\ci\zeromq_1599741307349\work\src\signaler.cpp:189)
2020-11-24 19:06:07,870 [ERROR] [asyncio] -> Exception in callback BaseSelectorEventLoop._read_from_self()
handle: <Handle BaseSelectorEventLoop._read_from_self()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 88, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\selector_events.py", line 119, in _read_from_self
    data = self._ssock.recv(4096)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Assertion failed: Connection reset by peer [10054] (C:\ci\zeromq_1599741307349\work\src\signaler.cpp:368)
Assertion failed: Connection reset by peer [10054] (C:\ci\zeromq_1599741307349\work\src\signaler.cpp:368)
```

No other indications of error appear. No pop-up,nothing.

Environment -

```
Windows 10 Home, 64bit
Spyder 4.1.5
Python 3.7.7
PYQT_VERSION = 329986
PYQT_VERSION_STR = 5.9.2
QOpenGLVersionProfile = <class 'PyQt5.QtGui.QOpenGLVersionProfile'>
QOperatingSystemVersion = <class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QOperatingSystemVersion'>
QT_VERSION = 329990
QT_VERSION_STR = 5.9.6
QVersionNumber = <class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QVersionNumber'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Spyder was crashing because it's connection (on 127.0.0.1) was being closed by an external process. Neither virus nor firewall was doing it. But this hints that something that intecepts the networking stack might be at fault. In my case it was NetWorx, a traffic monitor.

If you're having this problem (which you can detect by running spyder from the command line with --debug-verose), look at programs that intercept network traffic. This would be something like a firewall, traffic monitor, even a VPN.