# How to save Spyder IDE state without closing?

Tags: spyder

When I close Spyder it saves the state of the IDE (mainly which files are open in the editor pane). However, I am having problems with [crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64998671/1419711) and when I restart Spyder it recognizes an autosave files, but that only covers unsaved file edits, not the state of the IDE.  Is there any way to save the state without restarting Spyder?

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Unfortunately, we don't have a way to do that, sorry.